# Positioning infoWindow on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Here is the way it look like when open infoWindow. How can I place it at top right corner when opening infoWindow and is there any way to style it as pure rectangle.

[screenshot of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CEaj.png)

my code look like this

```
 var getDirection = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''

    });

var html ='<address><br>'+fromAddress+'</address><p>get directions from:</p><input id="from_Address" type="text" required><button id="go">Go</button><p><br><p id="error_msg" style="color:red;"></p><br>example: 121 belved Rd CA'
     getDirection.setContent(html);  
         getDirection.open(resultsMap);
```

Please help.

Comment: please check: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Comment: Thanks It will be helpful

Comment: Use the second parameter (the `anchor` parameter) to `open(map?:Map|StreetViewPanorama, anchor?:MVCObject)` or set the position of the InfoWindow. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demostrates the issue.

Comment: I'm just asking. Can we send position as second parameter instead of this    getDirection.open(resultsMap, marker);   ? For example getDirection.open(resultsMap, position);. position contains lat/lng value

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter (the anchor parameter) to open(map?:Map|StreetViewPanorama, anchor?:MVCObject) or set the position of the InfoWindow.

```
var html ='<address><br>'+fromAddress+'</address><p>get directions from:</p><input id="from_Address" type="text" required><button id="go">Go</button><p><br><p id="error_msg" style="color:red;"></p><br>example: 121 belved Rd CA'
getDirection.setContent(html);  
getDirection.open(resultsMap,marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following along the lines of the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744359/4180447), see code sample below:

```
var center = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map.getCenter()));
var boundaries = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map.getBounds()));
var newPosition = {lat: center.lat + Math.abs(boundaries.north - center.lat) / 2.75, lng: center.lng};
infoWindow.setContent('<strong>This infowindow should be located near the top, approx in the middle between the top point and the middle point.</strong>');
infoWindow.setPosition(newPosition);
```

Basically, you can get the boundaries of the map, and you have the center point. All you have to do, is to calculate the new position using such parameters.

Hope this helps.