# How to position Google Maps Infowindow box near the top and style as error

Tags: google-maps, position, styles, infowindow

I have developed this [plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bcj08pSu0o6RAB7IaYwE?p=preview):

Click on "View Canada Map with Message" to see the infowindow.

I want the infowindow to be positioned near the top of the map boundary or in the middle of the upper part. Also, I want to style the infowindow to appear as error message with error indicator icon.

See sample code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body >
    <input type="button" value="Init Map" onclick="initMap()">
    <input type="button" value="View Canada Map with Message" onclick="viewCanadaWithMessage()">

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
      var map;
      var infoWindow;
    var geocoder ;  
    var map;
    var palce;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      infoWindow.setPosition(map.getCenter());
      infoWindow.setContent('This is the center of the map');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
     //setTimeout(function(){initMap()}, 100);
    function doLoad() {

    }
    function viewCanadaWithMessage() {
        //geocoder.geocode({address:'Canberra, Australia'}, function(result, status){
        geocoder.geocode({address:'Canada'}, function(result, status){
            if (status == "OK") {
                map.setCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(3);
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                infoWindow.setContent('<strong>How I can locate this info window to be near the top, approx in the middle between the top point and the middle point? I want this window to display <span style="color:red">error message</span> with error indicator icon.</strong>');
                infoWindow.setPosition(map.getCenter());
                infoWindow.open(map);
            }
        });
    }
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    document.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        initMap();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, 'click', function() {
            alert('clicked');
        })
      }
    };

    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" >
    <!--
    document.writeln("<script async defer src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAh7w3_pTxbOFG3tT2P8ZDTwxDnp5A2GNw&callback=doLoad\"></script>");
    //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to calculate the position (lat, lng) which will be close to the upper side, and how I can style the infowindow to look like an error message?

Answer (score 1):

I did some analysis, and realized that I can find the approximate midpoint between the top and the center using this code snippet:

```
var center = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map.getCenter()));
var boundaries = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map.getBounds()));
var newPosition = {lat: center.lat + Math.abs(boundaries.north - center.lat) / 2.75, lng: center.lng};
infoWindow.setContent('<strong>How I can locate this info window to be near the top, approx in the middle between the top point and the middle point? I want this window to display <span style="color:red">error message</span> with error indicator icon.</strong>');
infoWindow.setPosition(newPosition);
```

See [plnker sample here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5TR2RZiQLZtTjlziXZTd?p=preview).

I hope that this is the right way. Please let me know if you better solution.

Now, I need to style the infowindow to appear as error. Appreciate your help.